# CGAffineTransform does not effect autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

recently I have been working with `CGAffineTransform` and `CATransform3D` on views and layers. When I apply transformation at layer level and especially on view level, shouldn't autolayout updates the frames of related views. For example, consider following layout `|H:[ViewA]-[ViewB]|`. If I apply transformation on just `ViewA`.

```
//We can either
    ViewA.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5) 
    ViewA.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.0)
```

shouldn't `ViewB` auto adjust it rect since `ViewA` height, width or position has changed after transformation. I also tried calling

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformations don't affect the `Frame` or `Bounds` of a view or the frame will be in an undefined state. To illustrate that: image you have a rectangular view with a frame of X:10, Y:10, W:100, H:100 and you rotate that by 45 degrees...what should the frame be?

From Apple's docs about the [transformation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform):

> If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

This explains why AutoLayout does not perform any updates.

Comment: thanks you right i missed that in documentation.. Actually i was logging the frame and i was getting the scaled result so i got confused that frame is chaging but not the related views. Just curious is there a method to turn transformation to identity and apply that difference to the frame.